# Difference in where clause and join

Tags: sql

im very new to SQL and currently working with joins the first time in my life. What I am trying to figure out right now is trying to get the difference between to queries.

Query 1:

```
SELECT name
FROM actor
JOIN casting ON id = actorid 
where (SELECT COUNT(ord) FROM casting join actor on actorid = actor.id AND ord=1) >= 30
GROUP BY name
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT name
FROM actor
JOIN casting ON id = actorid 
AND (SELECT COUNT(ord) FROM casting WHERE actorid = actor.id AND ord=1)>=30)
GROUP BY name
```

So I would think that doing

```
FROM casting join actor on actorid = actor.id
```

in the subquery is the same as

```
FROM casting WHERE actorid = actor.id.
```

But apparently it is not. Could anyone help me out and explain why?

Edit: If anyone is wondering: The queries are based on question 13 from http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations

Comment: These are strange queries.   Under normal circumstances, conditions for filtering go in the `WHERE` clause.  Conditions connecting tables go in the `ON` clause.

Comment: GROUP BY, but no aggregate functions - how come?

Comment: If name is a column from table actor, you can simplify this query with `...having count(casting.id) >= 30` instead of the where clause.

Comment: Regarding group by but no aggregate: True, I could have just used distinct command.

Still, I am sadly not really getting why these queries give different results.

I think of it like that: Using join command takes 2 tables and joins these based on similar values.
A where clause where you take actorid = actori.id is the same thing for me, looking for where the values are the same.

Maybe now someone will realize where exactly I am thinking wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the part that really looks like a "where" statement is only what's after the keyword `ON`. We sometimes fall on queries performing some data filtering directly at this stage, but its actual purpose is to specify the criteria used

A "**join**" is a very common operation that consists of associating the rows of two distinct tables according to a common criteria. For example, if you have, on one side, a table containing a client list in which each of them has a unique client number, and on a other side a order list table in which each order contains the client's number, then you may want to "resolve" the number of the latter table into its name, address, and so on.

Before SQL92 (26 years ago), the only way to achieve this was to write something like this :

```
SELECT client.name,
       client.adress,

       orders.product,
       orders.totalprice

  FROM client,orders
 WHERE orders.clientNumber = client.clientNumber
   AND orders.totalprice > 100.00
```

Selecting something from two (or more) tables induces a "cartesian product" which actually consists of associating every row from the first set which every row of the second one. This means that if your first table contains 3 rows and the second one 8 rows, the resulting set would be 24-row wide. And out of these, you use the WHERE clause to exclude basically everything and retain only rows in which the client number is the same on both side.

We understand that the size of the resulting set before filtering can grow exponentially if the contents of the different tables exceed a few rows (which is always the case) and it can get even worse if you imply more than two tables. Also, on the programmer's side, it rapidly becomes rather unreadable.

Therefore, if this is what you actually want to do, you now can explicitly tell the server about it, and specify the criteria at first, which will avoid unnecessary growing temporary subsets, while still letting you filter the results with WHERE if needed.

```
SELECT client.name,
       client.adress,

       orders.product,
       orders.totalprice

  FROM client

  JOIN orders
    ON orders.clientNumber = client.clientNumber

 WHERE orders.totalprice > 100.00
```

It becomes critical when performing multiple JOIN in a single query, especially when performing both INNER and OUTER joins.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd query your nested query takes the `actor.id` from its root query and only counts the results from that. In the 1st query your nested query counts results from all actors instead of only the specified one.

Comment: Ahh, this somehow makes sense.

But why so?